# Какой тег использовать в блоке

Tags: html, теги

Сайт вопросов и ответов. В нем есть список вопросов схема приблизительно такая:

**Столица Израиля Иерусалим или Тель-Авив?**
Марк | 7 часов назад | Города, Страны | Ответов (0)

---

**Ключ к игре Затерянные земли ледяное заклятие**
Никита | 20 часов назад | Игры, Развлечения | ответов: 0

---

и так далее.

Какой HTML-тег лучше использовать для строки "автор|время|категория|ответов" ?
Я использую `<p>`но поисковик воспримет это как текст, может есть специальный тег ?
адрес сайта если здесь разрешают: https://oc0.ru/

Comment: > "поисковик воспримет это как текст" 
А вам как надо?

Comment: спасибо за помощь. как текст, но не как абзац статьи, чем является тег <p>. может <li> использовать или  <div> или оставить как есть. Как посоветуете?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<p>` предназначен для абзацев
`<li>` для элементов списка
Ни один из них не подходит под эту ситуацию

Я бы поставил для заголовка тег `<H2>`, а строку с информацией об вопросе оставил бы без тега вовсе. Если тег в этой строке нужен только для оформления, то используйте `<div>`

Comment: спасибо за совет

Comment: Можете поставить галочку под ответом, чтобы отметить его как лучший

Answer (score 2):

Вот таким образом это делается ... 
h3 + span и всё

```css
h3 {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #888;
}

span:after {
  content: "|";
  padding: 0 5px;
  color:#999;
}

span:last-child:after {
  content: "";
 color:transparent;
}
```

```html
<h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</h3>
<span>Никита</span>
<span>20 часов назад</span>
<span>Игры и развлечения</span>
<span>ответов 0</span>
```

Пример в песочнице : https://codepen.io/MaximLensky/pen/MONNMj?editors=1100